# Silverstripe Implementing Tags

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm fairly new to silverstripe and php altogether so this is quite the learning curve for me.  I am well familiarized with MVC frameworks such as Rails so I don't think I'm completely lost; however I did spend quite a few days on this now and I just can't seem to figure it out.

I am trying to implement tags functionality on my website.  For example I have ArticleHolder which lists ArticleNews and I have created a text field in ArticleNews called Tags.  User can, when creating new article, enter tags and separate them by comma.

What I don't know how to do is grab all the news articles, search by tag and then return only those that contain the tag News.

```
public function PaginatedPages() { 
$paginatedItems = new PaginatedList(getNewsArticles()->sort('Date DESC'), $this->request); 
$paginatedItems->setPageLength(3); 
return $paginatedItems; 
} 
public function getNewsArticles(){ 
$newsArticles = ArticlePage::get();

foreach ($newsArticles as article){ 
$categories = article::get('category');

} 
return $newsArticles; 
}
```

I am not certain on how to grab the data from the tags text field and then check if the News is in there.  If it is not I want to remove it from $newsArticles.

That is my second question, how do I remove the ArticleNews from $newsArticle.

My third question is, can I do this on the database end?  So simply ::get() from the database where Tags contain the word News.  The delimiter is comma ','

Comment: The Silverstripe Blog module does. Have a look at the code for some help: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-blog/tree/master/code Have a look at BlogEntry.php and BlogTree.php

Comment: I will have a look later tonight.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to filter the list by a particular tag

$articles = ArticlePage::get()->filter('Tags:PartialMatch', 'News')

Though implementing tags with something like the TagField module would be better than comma separated strings. http://addons.silverstripe.org/add-ons/silverstripe/tagfield

Comment: I have never added a module like this before, I've tried looking as to how it is done but had no luck.  There is a readme file on github but according to that I just add a tag class which has 3 lines.  Doesn't seem to be right.  Could you tell me what I would need to do to get this working?  Do I copy the TagField.php from code folder, where do I put it?  How do I implement that with the Article example he has in the readme file?

Thank you for helping, spent quite a few days trying to figure this out.

Comment: ideally with SilverStripe modules you shouldn't copy code out of the  module folder. You should include the module folder along with your code and then use extensions to 'bolt on' functionality... golden rule with SilverStripe... don't hack the core or modules :)